# Perl Config::Simple: Adding Extra control characters (\\n) in the file

Tags: perl, configuration

I have a program that has to read and write in configuration(properties) file from a perl script. I am using Config::Simple for the reading and writing operations.

My question here is, I am able to read and write in properties file.
However,when I am trying to update in one of the config value in property value, it adds control characters (\n) and also want to remove default header created by "cfg-write()" method. I have tried searching forums and mentioned APIs, not information. Can someone throw some light?

When I am trying to call date/time function, its not adding any extra characters. However, when I am trying to execute svn command, it add extra character. I have tried using printing command on console, it works perfectly without control character

```
my $buildDate = strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S',localtime);
my $rev = `svn info --show-item revision`;
my $cfg = Config::Simple->import_from('temp.properties', \my %Config);
$cfg->param("builddate", $buildDate);
$cfg->param("revision", $rev);
$cfg->write() or die $cfg->error();
```

**Property-file:**

```
; Config::Simple 4.58
; Thu Apr 25 10:59:10 2019

version=Build Automation
revision=14794\\n
builddate=25/04/19 10:59:10
```

Expected Results:
1) Need to remove control character (\n) in revision config param
2) cfg-write or cfg-autosave() writes default header to the file, which I would like to remove/ignore

Actual Results:
1) Extra control character(\n) is added
2) Default header is added to the property file

Comment: `chomp $rev` to remove the newline from it.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the header?

Comment: First all, I would like to thank you for the method chomp. I wanted to remove, because, I am calling property file in ant. Is that possible?

Comment: Why not use [Config::Properties](http://p3rl.org/Config::Properties) then?

Comment: Thanks a ton! for that pointer. However, I do see hash charcter is included beginning and end of the file. Is there anyway to remove? Thank you once again! `###############

builddate = Updated
revision = 14794
version = ^/easycare/trunk

###############`

Comment: Hash character should be ignored by ant.

Comment: Thank you! appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @choroba. Excellent inputs

I tried using **Config::Properties::Commons**

```
 my $cpc = Config::Properties::Commons->new();
     $cpc->load('temp.properties');
     # Access
     $cpc->set_property( builddate => 'Updated' );
     $cpc->save('temp.properties');

Code for **Config::Simple**

    my $rev = `svn info --show-item revision /home/sudhir/Work/Workspaces/Eclipse/trunk`;

        chomp($ver);
        my $cfg = Config::Simple->import_from('easycare.properties', \my %Config) or 
     die print "ERROR: Not able to open easycare.properties file";


    $cfg->param("builddate", $buildDate);
    $cfg->param("revision", $rev);
    $cfg->param("version", $ver);
    $cfg->write() or die $cfg->error();
```